# dropdown list selected value does not refresh when using jQuery mobile empty function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following cascading select dropdown list in my page.

```
Country -> City
```

On my desktop, if I previously selected "USA" and "New York" and I then changed the country to France. The city dropdown would display "Choose a city" and this is what I want.

These are the code I used to populate the city list and set the default value.

```
$("#country").on("change", function(event) {
    getCities($("#country").val(), $("#city").val());
});

function getCities(country) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("index.cfm")) + "index.php/search/getCities?format=json"
        , dataType: "json"
        , data: {country:country}
        , success: function(data, status) {
            populateCities(data);
        }
    });
}

function populateCities(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $("#city").empty();

        $("#city").prepend($('<option></option>').attr("value", "").attr("selected", "selected").text("- Choose a city -"));
        $.each(data, function () {
            $("#city").append($('<option></option>').attr("value", this.CITY).text(this.CITY));
        });
    }
}
```

But on a mobile, the city dropdown still says "New York".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot

**edit:**

also tried these changes (as suggested below). still not working as intended

```
function populateAgencies(data) {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $("#agency").empty();

        $("#agency").prepend('<option value="" selected>- Choose a city -</option>');
        $.each(data, function () {
            $("#agency").append('<option value="'+this.CITY+'">'+this.CITY+'</option>');
        });("#city").enhanceWithin();
    }
}
```

Comment: There will be no difference between a desktop browser and a mobile one with what you are trying to do. There is something wrong with your code for sure. Can you update your question with the HTML and other Jquery code you might be using.

Comment: thanks for the tip. edited to show the full function used.

Comment: try populating your City div like this  -- http://jsfiddle.net/8jzh721L/ -- you may not need if you are not using  JQM 1.4 ($("#city").enhanceWithin();) so try with or without to see if any difference

Comment: tried your suggestion and still the same. thanks though

Comment: Have you tried .selectmenu("refresh")? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8jzh721L/1/

Comment: @ezanker  -- well spotted :), i had a feeling enhance wouldn't work in this case

Comment: @Tasos, thanks! We'll see if it works on the OPs mobile device...

Comment: Thanks ezanker. that works. Can you please make reply again so it's a proper answer? thanks :)